# what is the size of FS Info block in FAT32?

Tags: operating-system

In the `FAT32` there is another special reserved block called `FSInfo` sector. The block contains some information required by the operating system while cluster
allocation/deallocation to files. This information is also critical for `FAT16` based systems.

But in `FAT12` and `16` this information is calculated when ever required. This calculation at the time of allocation is not feasible in `FAT32` as the size of `FAT32` is very large and such calculations will consume a lots of time, so to save time this information is stored in the `FSInfo` block and is updated at the time of allocation/deallocation.

But i want to know the size of `FS Info` block in `FAT32`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of `FSinfo Block` in `FAT32` File system is `512 bytes` according to calculations.

For more visit and read:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#FS_Information_Sector

Comment: Will the block size still be 512 if the sector size of the storage is greater than 512?

Answer (score 0):

> [Microsoft Extensible Firmware Initiative FAT32 File System Specification, Version 1.03, December 6, 2000, Microsoft Corporation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/fatgen103.doc)
>
> [image]